# Custom user profile property in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, user-profile-property

I need to have a property on the profiles where I would save some custom data and also have the ability to make query on this property.
I working on SP Online.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible also in SharePoint OnLine.

These are the steps that you have to do:

- (Go to) Sharepoint Admin -> User Profiles -> Manage User Properties -> New Property

Here you have to choiche from some option.
For sure you will need to make the property *indexed*

- Then go to Search -> Manage Search Schema -> New Managed Properties

Here you have to *Add Mapping*
[image]
[image]
and check the *Searchable* box if needed, and *Retrievable* option

Comment: Did this work? I have not been able to get the properties returned in search on SPO.

Comment: it does for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just been puzzled by this myself and there's one more trick. Even a Full Crawl doesn't pick up the new property unless there's some data in it for at least one user.

After that, an Incremental Crawl was all I needed for it to appear in SharePoint Online.